# Ionic with es6: Camera is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, ngcordova

I've been working on Ionic in combination with Angular 1.5 and ES6, and I managed to inject the $cordovaCamera and $ionicPlatform into my controller. It is however not possible to directly use the Camera object. When I run the project, it gives me the following message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
at index.js:261
at Array.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:56238)
at onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js:2496)
at onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js:2477)
```

This is my code. It is simular to the code I wrote in a different blank project, where Camera actually does end up being inititalized.

```
class HomeController {

    constructor($cordovaCamera, $ionicPlatform) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$ionicPlatform = $ionicPlatform;
        // this.$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
        console.log("ready");
        this.$cordovaCamera = $cordovaCamera;
        //});
    }

  $onInit(){
    let self = this;

      this.$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
          console.log("ready");
          console.log(self.$cordovaCamera);  
          this.options = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          cameraDirection: 1,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        }; 
      });
  }


  takePicture(){
        this.$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            this.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
  }
}

export default HomeController;
```

In my index.js, Im injecting ngCordova and Ionic

```
import CameraComponent from './camera.component';

const home = angular
    .module('home', [ 'ionic',
     'ngCordova',
    ])
    .component('camera', CameraComponent)
    .config($stateProvider => {
        'ngInject';
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                component: 'camera'
            })
    })
    .name;

export default home;
```

The main issue might lie with the es6 notation. Is there a way I can fix this?